# Detecting if the user has left the website without logout or without completing a form

Tags: session, web

I'm trying to make a questionnaire and now I want to check if the user does not completed all the questions and left the webpage.

Can anyone help me how to detect that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   alert('user leaving');
};
```

Before that, you can set a ***flag*** (boolean variable) and based on that you can warn him using above code. For example intially set this flag to `false`, once user fills in all form, you can set it to `true`. And in above event, you can check if variable is `true` or `false` and warn him if he hasn't filled the form.

Comment: Dear Sarfraz, thank you very much for your answer please can you clarify it by using a sample code? if you can. Thank you again